# Disable Firefox Manual Credit Card Save

Tags: firefox

I'm attempting to prevent users from entering Addresses and  Credit Cards into Firefox Forms and AutoFill section. I want to gray out the boxes labeled as Saved Addresses and Saved Credit Cards in the below screenshot.  Our client audited our stations and dinged us on this setting.  We have the boxes for password grayed out and on a restricted user the AutoFill Addresses checkbox is unchecked but the agents can still, if they wanted to, choose to Save customer addresses or credit card data manually using the buttons to the right of those autofill checkboxes.

I'm not finding any options in the Firefox GPO settings for it.  There is a GPO for Preferences using JSON formatting but I can't find which option I should enter to gray those boxes out for users.  Below is the JSON I have in the Preference policy for Firefox but it only unchecks the Autofill checkboxes and users can still manually enter credit card data.  Any help in figuring out how to Gray out the two below boxes would be greatly appreciated.

{
"extensions.formautofill.creditCards.enabled": {
"Value": false,
"Status": "locked"
},
"extensions.formautofill.creditCards.available": {
"Value": false,
"Status": "locked"
},
"extensions.formautofill.addresses.capture.enabled": {
"Value": false,
"Status": "locked"
},
"extensions.formautofill.addresses.enabled": {
"Value": false,
"Status": "locked"
},
"extensions.formautofill.addresses.supported": {
"Value": false,
"Status": "locked"
}
}

[image]